# I need help finding the derivative?

Tags: matlab, math, mathematical-optimization, differential-equations

I need to find the derivative then create an anonymous function `v`, which is the vertical velocity of the projectile (that is, `v` is the derivative of the height function which is the above function).

```matlab
y = @(t) (m*v0*sin(theta)/gamma + g*m^2/gamma^2) * (1 - exp(-gamma/m*(t-t0))) ...
         - g*m/gamma * (t - t0) + y0;
```

Comment: Do you want to find the derivative numerically or symbolically? What have you tried? I ask because it is helpful to know where the difficulty is, you can get a more useful answer.

Comment: derivative symbolically i believe my teacher said that (m*v0*sin(theta)/gamma + g*m^2/gamma^2) is all a constant  as well as -g*m/gamma and (t - t0) + y0 now i needed to know the derivative of (1 - e^(-gamma/m*(t-t0))). he also gave me this as the parameters and have to plot them.  m = 10;
gamma = 0.1; 
t0 = 0;
y0 = 1;
g = 9.8
v0 = 100;
theta = pi/4;

Comment: If you can do it symbolically, you can find this on paper without doing any coding, it's an easy function to derive. I'm sure [this would help](https://www.google.com/search?q=derivative+of+exp(t)).

Comment: I wrote down this just plugged in the parameters (10*100*sin(pi/4)/0.1 + 9.8*10^2/0.1^2) * (1 - exp(-0.1/10*(t-0))) ...
    - 9.8*10/0.1 * (t - 0) + 1;  i don't know if thats correct

Comment: so is the derivative of  (1 - exp(-0.1/10*(t-0))) this ----->  0.1/10exp^(-0.1/10) (t-t0)

Comment: One thing I've learned over the years is always to test routines that claim to give the derivative. One way that I've found works well is given your function f and the derivative function fd to (numerically) integrate fd over an intervals (a,b) and compare the result with f(b)-f(a). By contrast comparing fd(x) with (f(x+h)-f(x))/h for small h is much trickier -- too big h and its not a good test and too small h and the result may be dominated by rounding error.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to do in [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), you can paste your function in there:

```
y(t) := (m*v0*sin(theta)/gamma + g*m^2/gamma^2) * (1 - exp(-gamma/m*(t-t0))) - g*m/gamma * (t - t0) + y0;
v(t) := diff(y(t),t);
display2d:false;
print(v(t));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1BDoMwDATvvMJHO20E5UjUryBZSkIjYYSKhcjrQ2g57uzYK3wk4VIyKsHwBhSzd2ZLC@onKFM7sQjDAyYjY/9PY09gAF9gIRwr2h9sxaBa7Yio8mrfl1XUCmpRn@TONfu95FOMeM0@lVzj07bOnHs/RJ634Jr1mxbFSyZXygk)

The output

```
(((m*sin(theta)*v0)/gamma+(g*m^2)/gamma^2)*gamma*%e^-(((t-t0)*gamma)/m))/m -(g*m)/gamma
```

can almost directly be pasted into MATLAB, you just need to replace the `%e^` with `exp()`:

```
v(t) = @(t)(((m*sin(theta)*v0)/gamma+(g*m^2)/gamma^2)*gamma*exp(-(((t-t0)*gamma)/m)))/m -(g*m)/gamma
```